# Date conversion in Stata

Tags: date, stata

Using Stata, I have a data set that includes date information in the following format: `9/10/11`. I need to be able to calculate the number of days between events. However, I am not having any luck converting the dates into a format that Stata can use. Can anyone help me with this? I've been searching online and none of the code I've found seems to work for me. Thanks!

Comment: This should help you: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/modules/dates.htm

Comment: I attempted to follow those instructions and was very unsuccessful. Perhaps part of the problem is that I'd like to be able to fix the dates within the data set, rather than as I import the data?

Comment: Please show what you did and what went wrong.

Comment: Okay, so here's a screen-shot of what my data looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z433v9hm4xmgvgu/Screenshot%202015-02-19%2018.34.49.png?dl=0

Then typed in: 
gen date1 = date(date, "dmy")

The output was: 
type mismatch
r(109);

Comment: See `help datetime`, to start.

Comment: The stat instructions say: You have a date stored in mystr, an example being "22/7/2010".  In
           this case, you want to create an SIF date instead of a datetime.
           You type

               . gen eventdate = date(mystr, "DMY")

I then typed: gen date1 = date(date, "DMY")
Again I got the error code r(109). Could this be because my variable is already named "date"?

Comment: You have month first, date second, and year third. So, the order should be "MDY". See the answer.

Comment: It's not clear if you have a numeric variable formatted as a _date_, or if it is actually a string. This is the key. If it's the former then you are ready to compute; dates in Stata are integers. If the latter, then use `date()` to convert. The main domain of the `date()` function is a string. You report a "type mismatch", so probably your `date` variable has numeric type and is formatted as _date_. Run `describe` and confirm.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help, specially the _Asking_ section and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It's difficult to help you if you don't follow the guidelines. As it is, your question is very low quality. "Not having any luck converting the dates..." is not the way to report a problem. Please, help us, help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
gen date1=date(date,"MDY")  # where the date inside the date function is your date variable
format date1 %d
```

Comment: The OP's belated addition of details shows that, although this is good advice for a string date variable which is indeed MDY, it is not the answer to the problem posted.

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the screenshot and the error message indicating `type mismatch` when the OP tries to use the `date()` function to produce daily dates.

Note that as links rot and as it is extra work for people to click on a link and work out what is going on, it is immensely better to describe your data explicitly in your question.

The OP's date variable is **already a numeric date variable with a date format so that what you see looks like a date**. This is implied indirectly by its colouring in the Data Editor, directly because what you see in the Editor looks like a date, and directly by the error message indicating that the variable is already numeric (the function requires a string argument, so a numeric argument is of incorrect type). So underneath a date presented as (say) 3/24/2014 is a numeric value 19806. One way is to see this is to type examples like

```
 display mdy(3,24,2014)
```

Hence the dates are already in a form that allows differences between dates to be calculated just by subtraction. A difference between daily dates is naturally not itself a date, but a time in days.

Although it's already been pointed out, I must echo the signals from experienced members here that problem reports of the form "no luck" or "very unsuccessful" with no indication of what you tried and what happened are completely useless and tend often to people ignoring your question or having to work hard to extract the real difficulty.

Note that even the one example in the original post was ambiguous as "9/10/11" could be 9 October or 10 September. That isn't central to the question, however.